# How to get data from ajax call to MVC controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a method in an MVC controller that queries a database, and returns a JSON object. It requires an ajax call to give it a date to query the database, however, in my current setup I'm getting `null` passed to the controller.

Here is my ajax request:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "Plot")',
                dataType: 'json',
                data: '04-15-2019 15:49:00',
                success: function (result) {
                    console.log(JSON.parse(result)
                }
            });
        }, 10000)
```

Here is my controller:

```
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetChartData(string timeStamp)
 {
        string output = queryDatabase(timeStamp);
        string test = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(output);
        return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Now, when I put a breakpoint after the `queryDatabase` call, the `timeStamp` variable is `null`, what am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "Plot")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {timeStamp: '04-15-2019 15:49:00'},
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(result)
            }
        });
    }, 10000)
});
```

And in the controller:

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetChartData()
{
    var timeStamp = Request["timeStamp"];
    var output = queryDatabase(timeStamp);
    var test = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(output);
    return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `[FromBody]`-attribute to force controller to read a simple type from the request body:

```
 using System.Web.Http;
 [HttpPost]
 public JsonResult GetChartData([FromBody]string timeStamp)
 {
        string output = queryDatabase(timeStamp);
        string test = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(output);
        return Json(output, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! When I put that in my code I get the `The type or namespace name 'FromBodyAttribute' could not be found`, is there something I need to import for this to work?

Comment: It is found in: System.Web.Http namespace (I'll assume you are using "Legacy" Asp.Net MVC, not Asp.Net Core

Answer (score 1):

When you use `Post` type and dataType `JSON` on your Ajax call u need to pass data in this format `{title:data}` in ur case it will be

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: '@Url.Action("GetChartData", "Plot")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: {timeStamp: '04-15-2019 15:49:00'},
            success: function (result) {
                console.log(JSON.parse(result)
            }
        });
    }, 10000)
```

In your controller it will automatically catch data in argument. Provided just double check ur URL in Ajax call